# How to make a table with permissions? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

So I tried to make a basic table with database integration, which worked flawlessly. Now I need to make a table that adds you the permission to edit the data you inserted into the form. But I need it to only give the person who made the form the permissions to edit it. Below I added my current progress without the permissions added. Currently I finished the Jetstream page with laravel, it has login and register so I'd want the username to be the authed person to edit the data. Is there any easy way to do it?

The controller I made:

```
    `$rada= new Raja;
    $rada->id=$req->id;
    $rada->raja_nimi=$req->raja_nimi;
    $rada->raja_asukoht=$req->raja_asukoht;
    $rada->save();
    return redirect('list');`
```

The view file:

```html
<form action="add" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Raja ID"> <br> <br>
    <input type="text" name="raja_nimi" placeholder="Raja nimi"> <br> <br>
    <input type="text" name="raja_asukoht" placeholder="Raja asukoht"> <br> <br>
<button type="submit">Lisa</button>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to store the id of the author in your controller, for example...

```
$rada= new Raja;
$rada->id=$req->id;
$rada->raja_nimi=$req->raja_nimi;
$rada->raja_asukoht=$req->raja_asukoht;
$rada->author_id = Auth::id();
$rada->save();
```

Then when you come to update the post in your controller you'd implement a check to make sure that the user owns the post...

```
$post = Raja::find($req->id);
if(Auth::id() == $post->author_id) {
    //Update functionality here
} else {
    //Redirect to 401 or send response message
}
```

A more Laravel appropriate way to perform a check when the user attempts to save a model would be to use a policy, you can find an example here
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#policy-responses

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one more question. Does the below code go into the controller itself also? Or does it need another file? @Luke.T
`
$post = Raja::find($req->id);
if(Auth::id() == $post->author_id) {
    //Update functionality here
} else {
    //Redirect to 401 or send response message
}
`

Comment: @DatHerd Yes you can put it into the update method of your controller 

Comment: Hey so, the code doesnt seem to work for me. Just got around testing it and it still lets everyone edit. This is the controller for the updating part in RajaController  > [link](https://pastebin.com/XuY8Ut0n) Then I went to the adding part in RadaController and this is the code for that [link](https://pastebin.com/itmLCddy). @Luke.T

Comment: @DatHerd There’s no reason why the method shouldn’t work. Check that both your Auth::id() and the $post ->author_id have the correct values.

Comment: They all do, when a new "rada" is added then it displays the author_id in the database next to it also. But when someone else tries to edit the "rada" with a different author_id they still can @Luke.T

Comment: I'm not sure how I can assist you. You correctly have an author id check in your update method [here](https://pastebin.com/XuY8Ut0n) on line 5. If it's not working there must be an alternate reason which is unrelated to this question. @DatHerd